# Drag text from one INPUT to another INPUT without text being removed from source INPUT

Tags: javascript, input, drag, undo

I have two text INPUT elements A and B.

I want the user to be able to select part or all of the text from A and drag to B but for the text not to disappear from A.

Say 'A' contains 'quick brown fox', the user highlights the word 'fox' and drags it to 'B'.  By default box 'A' now contains 'quick brown ', but I want it to still say 'quick brown fox'.

I don't want 'A' to be readonly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function preventDragNDropChangesOn(inputElement) {
  let previousValue = inputElement.value
  let isDragged = false
  let wasDropped = false

  /*
  * event order:
  *   dragstart (prepare for possible text cutting)
  *   drop (input text was not cut out yet at this point, save it to revert it later)
  *   change (input text is already cut out at this point - revert it to the previous value)
  *   dragend (set variables to initial state)
  */

  inputElement.addEventListener('dragstart', () => isDragged = true)
  document.body.addEventListener('drop', () =>
    (wasDropped = isDragged) && (previousValue = inputElement.value))
  inputElement.addEventListener('change', (e) =>
    isDragged && wasDropped && (e.target.value = previousValue))
  inputElement.addEventListener('dragend', () => isDragged = wasDropped = false)
}
```

```js
const inputElement = document.querySelector(".js-controlled-input")

preventDragNDropChangesOn(inputElement)

function preventDragNDropChangesOn(inputElement) {
  let previousValue = inputElement.value
  let isDragged = false
  let wasDropped = false
  let shouldRevertChanges = () => isDragged && wasDropped
  
  document.body.addEventListener('drop', () => wasDropped = isDragged)
  inputElement.addEventListener('dragstart', () => isDragged = true)
  inputElement.addEventListener('dragend', () => (isDragged = false) || (wasDropped = false))
  inputElement.addEventListener('input', (e) =>
    shouldRevertChanges()
    ? (e.target.value = previousValue)
    : (previousValue = e.target.value) 
  )
}
```

```html
<input class="js-controlled-input" value="quick brown fox"/>
<input class="js-target"/>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/91o9mpaz/4/

---

IE11 compatible solution:

```
function preventDragNDropChangesOn(inputElement) {
  let previousValue = inputElement.value
  inputElement.addEventListener('dragstart', function () { previousValue = inputElement.value })
  inputElement.addEventListener('dragend', function () { setTimeout(function() {inputElement.value = previousValue }, 1) })
}
```

Comment: That's brilliant.  I am just spending some understanding how it works..

Comment: Would it be possible to apply to lots of IINPUT elements?  I find that if I have more than one with class "js-controlled-input" only the first one behaves correctly

Comment: @RichardBriggs Sure, here's an example https://jsfiddle.net/91o9mpaz/5/

Comment: Its works - I just copied the new version of the function.   I am very gratefull, how do I give thanks/stars on this site?

Comment: @RichardBriggs On this site you can upvote/accept answers and that's about it. Funny thing I've just learned - if you hold ctrl while dragging, the text is not removed from the source input :D

Comment: Oh yes your'e right and you get a little plus symbol while dragging.  My next challenge is drag and drop text on a mobile / touch screen.  I have tried up-voting - my lowly reputation on here wont allow this just yet :)  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Having some trouble with Internet IE 11 (not tested other versions of IE), but Chrome, Edge and FireFox are OK.   In IE you can't drag the text to another browser window and also the text is deleted as before.  On another thread I read about a no-propogate option maybe that will help but I am not where ti place that in the code.

Comment: @RichardBriggs I don't have access to IE so I can't check the behavior. Maybe this will work: https://jsfiddle.net/91o9mpaz/6/

Comment: Same problem persists I am afraid.  Your talent is my only hope.

Comment: This page mentions IE and a possible workaround with a 'catch' not sure if its related or if it helps http://mereskin.github.io/dnd/

Comment: @RichardBriggs this should work in IE11 https://jsfiddle.net/91o9mpaz/7/

Comment: Almost! - except this time it wont let you drag the text to another browser or app window.

Comment: @RichardBriggs I'm afraid that dragging between windows depends on browser and system settings. See https://superuser.com/questions/1172989/why-doesnt-usual-dragdrop-work-in-windows-10?rq=1 https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/dragging-dropping-pictures-text-no-more-in/7e6116cf-92b1-4c99-98b3-52d0169d4c50

Comment: I see, it seems IE 11 is rejecting drag and drop from other sources too, not just my text boxes.